# unity wont let me attatch object to variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity wont let me drag and drop a game object into the variable

heres my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;


public class GameManager : Singleton<GameManager>
{
    [SerializeField] private Player currentPlayer;

    public Player CurrentPlayer
    {
        get { return currentPlayer; }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(currentPlayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are attaching a gameobject that has a `Player` component? Take into account that you are attachiing the `Player` component that is inside the gameObject you are probably dragging.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay im not too sure what you mean, I try to drag the player component that is separate to the component im dragging the player object into, but it just blocks it.

Comment: If you want to interact with a script as a component in the Inspector tab, it must inherit Monobehaviour. Public attributes being addressable from the UI in Unity is a Monobehviour-specific implementation by Unity, for the Unity environment, and not applicable to all C# objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your `public class GameManager : Singleton<GameManager>` should be a monobehaviour.
Monobehaviours are the type to inherit from when you to add functionality to a gameObject. You cannot drag whatever to a script that just hold a `[SerializeField]`.

You need to have a `Monobehaviour` inherited class as a component of a gameobject (meaning that it should be attached to it). There is where you can drag the componenets into the `public` or the `private [SerializeField]` fields shown in the editor when you select the correspoding gameobject.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZaG5fZ4d4o&list=PL86WBCjNmqh4bDQycScKKlP0ETkjo39gG&index=11 this is the tutorial im following

Answer (score 0):

Your script must inherit from Monobehavior for you to be able to do that. And since `Singleton` is a generic type, that wont work.